# Does (HTML.Action) send another request to the server other than the main request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I am wondering if (HTML.Action) send another request to the server other than the main request.

For example, when Razor renders the below view. Does it send a new request to the server to execute the action (SearchResults)?

```
@Html.Action("SearchResults", "MySearch", 
    new { query = new QueryParameters(Request.QueryString["search"]) })
```

Comment: Can you provide an example? Are you talking about action links? Or action results?

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see whether it send another request or not using network tab under developer tools.`Html.Action` is just a helper method like any other ,purpose of it is rendering view via calling another action , all it happens when razor renders page.So complete html send to browser in a single request so main request.

Answer (score 0):

When you are rendering actions/partials in a View there is only one request.
If you want to test this you can debug it in your global.asax with this method:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```